# Log file permissions in Linux

Tags: linux, permissions, logging, file-permissions

I am trying to write a simple script that monitors `/var/log/messages` file. The file by default doesn't have read permission for users, when I allow read access to this file my script works perfectly, but the problem is that file gets rewritten each time I restart the system and all my changes get lost. Is there a way to change its default permissions?

Thanks.

Comment: which Linux distro are you using?

Comment: I am using OpenSUSE 11.0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There *are* permissions management setups that don't require you to use `sudo` -- you could give the user running the script access to the group that owns `/var/log/messages` (`adm`, on my laptop here).  Alternately, use `NOPASSWD` in the sudoers entry for the script, so that you don't have to store a password in the script.

If you're *really* dead-set on letting the world see what's in `/var/log/messages` (and I'd *strongly* recommend against it -- there really can be private stuff in there) then what's setting your permissions back to default is probably `logrotate`, so check out your logrotate config and find the stanza that's doing your `/var/log/messages` rotation and change it.

Comment: it seems that on my computer only root user has access to that file :(

Answer (score 2):

If you do use sudo to grant access, then you need to be careful to limit the access scope properly.  I would recommend using something like this in your sudoers file:

```
scriptuser  ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/cat /var/log/messages
```

That will allow 'scriptuser' to perform the exact command presented without entering a password.

Comment: I like this solution, but I feel like it could be really confusing to certain users. To me at least it would be really confusing to be able to `cat` a file and not `tail` it or something.

Comment: @JosephSilvashy: You can also set up command groups and allow any "read only" text processing commands you want while keeping my answer pretty well intact. I leave configuring said grouping as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution is to run the monitor script with sufficient privilege to be able to read the file.

This is because the `/var/log/messages` permission is carefully chosen to hide any sensitive information that accidentally ends up in that log file.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I want to run the script when system starts with no user interactions and I don't want to store sudo password in my script file. 
There are lots of other files that contain more sensitive information and allow to change their permissions just fine.

Comment: create another user and use group permissions.

Comment: So start the script form root's crontab then.
It doesn't have to run from your user account.

Comment: it is a gui script, and I had no luck so far running gui applications not from current user. Group permissions for this file are always set to 0.

Comment: A GUI script that runs with no user interactions... WTF?

Comment: It sounds like you have a GUI application that starts when the user logs in? Is that the case?